# Basics of Haskell compiling

Tags: haskell, parsing, compilation, ghc

I'm working on the 2nd Euler's problem, but for now I'm just trying to define the Fibonacci sequence. Currently, I have my Fib function defined as

```
Fib 0 = 0
Fib 1 = 1
Fib x = Fib (x - 1) + Fib (x - 2)
```

Because I want the program to depend on my keyboard input, I used

```
main = do
        putStrLn "Enter desired Fibonacci index: "
        "index" <- getLine
        putStrLn Fib x
```

And defined x as `x = read "index"`

I'm pretty sure I'm messing up both the indentation, and my syntax. Depending on how I modify the code, running "ghc /dir/file.hs gets me stuff like "Not in scope: data constructor `Fib'", or "parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)". I really, really don't know what the heck I'm doing, especially with regard to how to set up the .hs to be compiler friendly. I've read through about 7 tutorials on compiling with GHC, but they all seem to skip the part where they explain the basic requirements of compiling.

Please let me know how I can be more specific if that would help. I think the two things I'm trying to understand is how the whole "main" thing is related to compiling, and how I can get it to recognized I HAVE defined Fib as a function, even though it says its not in scope.

PS: I can't figure out the indentation here, Stack seems to want to put everything in one line, so I have to separate it all out. Sorry.

Comment: If you don't already know them, other functions that will be useful for you full solution are:`sum`, `filter` and `takeWhile`.

Answer (score 9):

The first letter of Fib should not be capitalized.  Capitalized words indicate a type.  Functions should start with a lower case letter.

The compiling looks fine!

You'll also get a few other errors when you compile.  Remember that `putStrLn` takes a `String` as an argument.  Your `fib` function returns an `Integer`.  You can use `show` to convert a value into a `String`.

Comment: Just a note: capitalized identifiers indicate data constructors (as in this error) or type constructors (in type context) or modules names (in module context).

Answer (score 5):

Just summing it up:

- Your indentation looks ok.
- Function names cannot begin with an uppercase letter. Capitalized identifiers are used for constructors, type and module names only.
- You can test your stuff with an interactive interpreter and don't need a main function.
- You need a variable name if you want to store the result of some computation, so the `getLine` result should be bind to a `index`, not `"index"`. The first will be a string *variable*, not a string *value*.
- `putStrLn` takes only one parameter (the string to be shown). In your program, it receives *two* parameters: a function `Fib` and some undefined `x`.
- By the way, you need to define `x`, probably using `read` to convert the input string to an integer value.
- Also, `putStrLn` needs a String and `Fib` returns an integer, you need to convert it before passing it in: `putStrLn (show (Fib x))`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your code, fixed so that you can actually compile it.

```
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib x = fib (x - 1) + fib (x - 2)

main = do
        putStrLn "Enter desired Fibonacci index: "
        index <- getLine
        print (fib (read index))
```

You had a couple of problem. Functions start with lower case letters. Secondly, you can't apply `putStrLn` to the result of `fib` because `fib` returns an integer and `putStrLn` expects a `String`. So I've used `print` instead. Also, you tried to use a string (`"index"`) as a variable. It's true that you get a `String` from `getLine` but it has to be stored in a variable and a variable doesn't have quotes around it.

Note, just as Barry said, you don't really need the `main` function. Just put your fibonacci function in a file, load it into ghci and call the function from there. Easy peasy.

Also, note that your fibonacci function is horribly slow, but I hope you're already aware of that.

Good luck with the Euler problems. I've found it quite fun to use Haskell to solve them.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother with a main function. Just launch ghci, load your module, and invoke the fib function directly.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, `getLine` returns a string, so you should bind that to a variable

```
do
   idx <- getLine
   print $ fib $ read idx
```

Comment: That's not going to work, as fib takes a numeric value. The last line would have to be `putStrLn $ show $ fib $ read idx`. Also, you can use `print` for `putStrLn . show`.

Comment: Right you are. My Haskell is getting rusty.